# .NET MAUI with Xamarin.Essentials - Get Display Info

Tags: maui, xamarin.essentials

I'm a Flutter developer and my company is considering moving over to .NET MAUI, so I spent the weekend trying it out but came across a flaw that I cant seem to get around. Using Xamarin.Essentials to get the screen size with
`Global.height = Microsoft.Maui.Devices.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height` and Width
I get a return of the actual screen size in pixels be it from my attached S10 Ultra or the Pixel 5 Emulator. However this is not the actual size the debugger is using to draw on my screen so if I describe a View (Widget) as being Global.height *.5 I get a drawn height on my screen of about 70 - 75% of the actual screen height.
Is there a way around this? or a setting I am missing? It's quite important that this works correctly in order to make a truly responsive application.

MainPage.xmal

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mct="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Behaviors;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
             x:Class="Bears_Portal.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <mct:StatusBarBehavior x:Name="statusBar"/>
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <Image
            Source="ambulance.jpeg"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            Aspect="AspectFill">
        </Image>
        <Rectangle
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                   Opacity=".85">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#1A2373"
                          Offset="0.01" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#3949AB"
                          Offset="1.0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <BoxView
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,.045"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            Color="White"
            CornerRadius="0,0,10,10">
            <BoxView.Shadow>
                <Shadow
                    Brush="Black"
                    Offset="0,5"
                    Radius="40"
                    Opacity="1">
                </Shadow>
            </BoxView.Shadow>
        </BoxView>
        <BoxView
            x:Name="BottomSheet"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".04,1,1,0"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            Color="White"
            CornerRadius="10,10,0,0">
            <BoxView.Shadow>
                <Shadow
                    Brush="Black"
                    Offset="0,-5"
                    Radius="40"
                    Opacity="1">
                </Shadow>
            </BoxView.Shadow>
        </BoxView>
        <Border
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".99,0,.15,.04"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            Stroke="#1A2373"
            StrokeThickness="1"
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 5">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#7986CB"
                          Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#3949AB"
                          Offset="1.0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <Border.Shadow>
                <Shadow
                    Brush="Black"
                    Offset="2,5"
                    Radius="5"
                    Opacity="0.6"
                    />
            </Border.Shadow>
            <Label
            Text="REFRESH"
            FontSize="Micro"
            TextColor="White"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label.Shadow>
                    <Shadow
                    Brush="Black"
                    Offset="0,5"
                    Radius="2"
                    Opacity="0.8"
                    />
                </Label.Shadow>
            </Label>
            <Border.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Refresh"/>
            </Border.GestureRecognizers>
        </Border>
        <Label
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,0,.6,.04"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            Text="BEARS EMPLOYEE PORTAL"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label.Shadow>
                <Shadow
                    Brush="Black"
                    Offset="2,2"
                    Radius="5"
                    Opacity="0.6"
                    />
            </Label.Shadow>
        </Label>
        <Border
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".01,0,.15,.04"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            Stroke="#1A2373"
            StrokeThickness="1"
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 5">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#7986CB"
                          Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#3949AB"
                          Offset="1.0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <Border.Shadow>
                <Shadow
                    Brush="Black"
                    Offset="2,5"
                    Radius="5"
                    Opacity="0.6"
                    />
            </Border.Shadow>
            <Label
            Text="MENU"
            FontSize="Micro"
            TextColor="White"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Label.Shadow>
                    <Shadow
                    Brush="Black"
                    Offset="0,5"
                    Radius="2"
                    Opacity="0.8"
                    />
                </Label.Shadow>
            </Label>
            <Border.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Menu"/>
            </Border.GestureRecognizers>
        </Border>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xmal.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    bool bottomSheet = false;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        statusBar.StatusBarColor = Colors.White;
        statusBar.StatusBarStyle = CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.StatusBarStyle.DarkContent;
    }
    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
        Global.height = height;
        Global.width = width;
    }
    private void Refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bottomSheet = !bottomSheet;
    }
    private void Menu(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bottomSheet = !bottomSheet;
        if (bottomSheet) { BottomSheet.HeightRequest = Global.height*.5; } else { BottomSheet.HeightRequest = Global.height * .04; }
        Console.WriteLine($"HEIGHT {Global.height}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Width {Global.width}");
    }

}
```

[PIXEL 5 Android 12.1 API 32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxIqV.png)

Comment: The emulator window is not necessarily equal to the physical size of a real device as it can be resized. Do you need the physical size? Can you explain a little more about what you want to accomplish and maybe provide a graphic to visualize the issue you want to solve? MAUI just like XF uses device independent pixels to draw on the screen and sizes are relative. Note: `Microsoft.Maui.Devices.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo` is not from Xamarin.Essentials, that's MAUI (assembly: *Microsoft.Maui.Essentials*).

Comment: You may want to use the Page's height instead of trying to use the device's physical size or height in pixels. The Page's size is only known once it has been allocated. You could therefore override `OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)` and then calculate your desired height for the `HeightRequest` property of the BottomSheet view like this: `BottomSheet.HeightRequest = height * 0.5;`.

Comment: Maui by default would return the Width and Height based on native platforms, you should always divide it with MainDisplayInfo.Density to get the correct value.

Comment: I think my answer maybe along ewerspej's lines in flutter we use ```MediaQuery.of (context).size.height,``` and this can't be called before the build.

Comment: Using On size allocated has returned the same value as height/density, upon requesting 50% of screen size I'm getting about 30%. My result was 411 wide by 780 tall which is exactly what flutter returns when i have removed the top and bottom padding. However ! the screen height it is drawing is around 1300, the device's actual pixel height is 3080.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  What you’ve posted doesn’t really demonstrate anything

Comment: code added above

Comment: You can check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device/display?tabs=android).